# securing development sandboxes with Azure SQL server

Tags: networking, security, development

Hello we are attempting to setup development systems in Azure using Azure SQL as a service. The problem we are encountering is that Azure SQL as a service does not show in the console any way to designate an IP address or subnet.  We are attempting to isolate traffic from these sandbox servers but do not see a clear way to do it with the designated development IP addresses.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.